# Add link to record to a plain text email

Tags: email, email-template

We have a requirement to add record link to our plain text email. Originally we were doing something like:

```
'https://eu3.salesforce.com/' + Id
```

However, this will stop working when Salesforce decides to change instance.

Two approaches I can think of is:

1. Apply a custom domain. I need to discuss with our business team about that.
2. Use a custom setting to record the instance so in the future we only need to update one place.

Both ways should be working but still has some limits. Is there any other suggestion for this?

Comment: Have you checked the URL class? - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_url.htm#!

Comment: @BorisBachovski Didn't check that till you pointed out. Thanks for that. Your comment together with Santanu's answer resolved my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a link to the record to a plain text email template, simply use

for example, if it is a case record

```
{!Case.Link}
```

For custom object, use `{!CustomObject__c.Link}`

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there a way to achieve this in a SingleEmailMessage text body?

Comment: you just create a template and in `SingleEmailMessage` specify `setTemplateId`